# Play Framework Driver not found: [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver]

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc, playframework

> Driver not found: [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver]

I don't can play recognizer `ojdbc6.jar`

I make 2 ways

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-java_2.11" % "2.3.10"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

when run project appear

> sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.oracle#ojdbc14;10.

**Eclipse Build Path**

configure build path >> Add External JARs

none of way find oracle jdbc

in my `application.conf`

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I used play version 2.2

Comment: Do you have the Oracle driver in your build.sbt? Something like `libraryDependencies += "com.oracle" % "ojdbc14" % "10.2.0.4.0"`.

Comment: Yes, but appear [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.oracle#ojdbc14;10.
2.0.4.0!ojdbc14.jar

Comment: Hi, was this ever resolved for you?